# Error reading MIME types using Python

Tags: python-2.7, mime-types

I'm writing a python script that will read file extensions, MIME types and file signatures so I can determine if any of those are missing or corrupt, and to establish the types of the files in the given directory.

So far I've got:

```
import magic, os

def get_ext(dirPath):
    foldercount = 0
    filecount = 0
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(dirPath):
            break
        else:
            print "Directory doesn't exist!"
            continue
    includePath = raw_input("Do you want to include the complete path to the files in the output?: Y/N\n")

    if includePath.upper() == "Y":
        for rootfolder, subfolders, files in os.walk(dirPath):
            foldercount += len(subfolders)
            filecount += len(files)
            for f in files:
                name = f
                path = os.path.join(rootfolder, f)
                ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
                if ext != "":
                    print "Filename: " + str(path) + "\t\tExtension: " + str(ext) + "\tMIME: "
                else:
                    print "Filename: " + str(path) + "\t\tExtension: no extension found"
        print "Found {0} files in {1} folders".format(filecount, foldercount)

    elif includePath.upper() == "N":
        for rootfolder, subfolders, files in os.walk(dirPath):
            foldercount += len(subfolders)
            for f in files:
                name = f
                path = os.path.join(rootfolder, f)
                ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
                if ext != "":
                    print "Filename: " + str(name) + "\t\tExtension: " + str(ext)
                else:
                    print "Filename: " + str(name) + "\t\tExtension: no extension found"
        print "Found in {0} folders".format(foldercount) 

    else:
        print "Wrong input, try again"


def getMagic(dirPath):
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(dirPath):
            break
        else:
            print "Directory doesn't exist!"
            continue
    for rootfolder, subfolders, files in os.walk(dirPath):
        for f in files:
            bestand = f 
            mymagic = magic.Magic(mime=True)
            mytype = mymagic.from_file(bestand)
            print mytype
            print ("The MIME type of the file %s is %s" %(bestand, mytype))

dirPath = raw_input("Directory to check files in: ")        
get_ext(dirPath)       
getMagic(dirPath)
```

get_ext() works as it should, giving me a files name and extension.
However, when I try to fetch the MIME type it somehow throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nick/workspace/Proto/asdfasdf.py", line 80, in <module>
    getMagic(dirPath)     
  File "/home/nick/workspace/Proto/asdfasdf.py", line 74, in getMagic
    mytype = mymagic.from_file(bestand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magic.py", line 75, in     from_file
    raise IOError("File does not exist: " + filename)
IOError: File does not exist: 2
```

I know for a fact that file '2' does exist, being a plain text document.
It does give me the MIME if i hardcode the path to a file in the script, but I want the script to traverse a directory giving me all mimes of the files in it.

Can somebody explain why it throws this error and how to fix this issue?
I am using the python-magic module installed using pip install python-magic

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for `os.walk` we can see that

> filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

You need to get the complete path as

```
bestand = os.path.join(rootfolder, f)
```

Comment: changed bestand = os.join(rootfolder,f) to os.path.join.
Otherwise it worked great, Thanks!